# Safari Javascript parent.frames.length

Tags: javascript, safari, frames

I get a parse error from Safari with this code:

```
for (var i=0; i<parent.frames.length; i++){...}
```

doing

```
alert(parent.frames.length);
```

works and outputs the correct value which is 5.

I also tried but failed:

```
var len = parent.frames.length
alert(len); //Correct
for (var i=0; i<len; i++){...} //Parse Error
```

When i type this code into the console directly, it works fine. And it also works fine in other browsers.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: What exactly is the parse error reported?

Comment: the console doesnt give me any more info. It just says parse error and then the line number. which points to the line of the for loop.

Comment: It seems like an odd issue.  What happens if you explicitly cast to a number, e.g. `var len = +parent.frames.length;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make it work, i just added a space after <.

```
for(var i=0; i < parent.frames.length){...}
```

But i'm still stumped as to why the one without a space gives a parse error.